# How to convert picocli groovy-grape script to native standalone app?

Tags: groovy, executable-jar, graalvm, picocli

I have a made my first groovy CLI app with picocli. Now, I want it to be available for use without any JVM installed on the client machine, maybe with the use of GraalVM.
This is for an opensource project:
https://github.com/kchaitanya863/db2csv

Comment: Thanks for choosing picocli in your project. Tip: 2.0.3 is quite old, you may want to upgrade to a later version. The latest version at this time is 3.9.5. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to:

- statically compile your groovy script
- make the `args` variable available after static compilation with

```
final String[] args = getProperty("args") as String[]
```

- specify a reflection configuration file for the classes dynamically loaded/invoked using reflection by Groovy ([this may be useful](https://gist.github.com/wololock/e99d748e724bf5ae6ce930c1b8cb9a90))
- specify a reflection configuration file for the classes loaded/invoked using reflection by picocli. The `picocli-codegen` module [provides](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/tree/master/picocli-codegen) a `picocli.codegen.aot.graalvm.ReflectionConfigGenerator` tool to generate the configuration file.
- If your script has any `@Grape` dependencies, you may need to turn off the Grape dependency manager with `-Dgroovy.grape.enabled=false` and add all dependencies to the classpath manually instead

Credit: I got most of these tips from [this article](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/graalvm-groovy-grape-creating-native-image-of-standalone-script/) by Szymon Stepniak

Answer (score 1):

Another easy option is to dockerize your script (read this blog about how to do it https://groovy-lang.gitlab.io/101-scripts/docker/basico-en.html)

If you want to build a linux executable you need to change your project:

- convert to a gradle project (maven is also an option but gradle has a lot of plugins)
- change your script to a class with a tipical main (and move it to the standard directory src/main/groovy/mypackage)
- add some tasks into you build.gradle similar to these  https://gitlab.com/snippets/1797638